# Descargar objeto como archivo en AngularJS

Tags: html5, angularjs, typescript

Buenas noches! Estoy creando un componente en Angular, al cual le paso un texto en un formato determinado y lo convierte en formato JSON. Hasta ahí todo bien.
La cuestión es que ahora quiero que al pulsar un boton, me descargue el objeto creado previamente como un archivo JSON, y por mucho que he ojeado no encuentro la forma.
Aquí dejo la parte del código TS donde creo el objeto en formato JSON:

```
> onSubmit(){
>     this.stats = this.FIFAstatsform.get('fifastats').value;
>     this.stats = this.stats.replace(/\n/g, " ");
>     this.statsplitted = this.stats.split(" ", 58);
>     this.jsonobject = '{';
>     for (let stat of this.statsplitted){
>       if (this.statsplitted.indexOf(stat)%2==0){
>         this.jsonobject=this.jsonobject+'"'+stat+'"'+':';
>       }
>       if (this.statsplitted.indexOf(stat)%2!=0 && this.statsplitted.length-1 != this.statsplitted.indexOf(stat)){
>         this.jsonobject=this.jsonobject+stat+',';
>       }
>       if (this.statsplitted.indexOf(stat)%2!=0 && this.statsplitted.length-1 == this.statsplitted.indexOf(stat)){
>         this.jsonobject=this.jsonobject+stat+'}';
>       }
>     }
>     this.creado = true;
```